# Heights of dropdown and button are different. Dash Plotly python

Tags: python, html, css, alignment, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a dashboard with dash in python and I am trying to align 2 dropdowns and a button horizontally

this is the html.Div that I am working with

```
html.Div([
    html.Div(
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown 1',
            options=list(df_.columns),
            multi=True,
            clearable=True,
            searchable=True,
            placeholder='Required Rows',
            optionHeight=20,
        ), style={
            'width': '39%',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'vertical-align': 'top',
        }
    ),

    html.Div(
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown 2',
            options=list(df_.columns),
            multi=True,
            clearable=True,
            searchable=True,
            placeholder='Required Columns',
            optionHeight=20,
        ), style={
            'width': '39%',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'vertical-align': 'top',
        }
    ),

    html.Div(
        html.Button(
            "Do something",
            id='button_1',
        ), style={
            'width': '20%',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'vertical-align': 'top'
        }
    )

]),
```

[image]

Is there any way to make the height of the `do something` button the same as that of the dropdown even when the window is resizing.

Or

Is there any way to make the height of dropdowns same as that of the button, which stays the same even when resizing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the elements to the same `line-height`.